# for i in `cat file` type with 2 variables and 2 files

Tags: bash, for-loop

i have this script

```
for i in `cat file`
do
echo $i
done
```

how can i have in same loop 2 variables from 2 different files

to get

```
echo $i + $f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while IFS='|' read -r i j; do echo $i and $j; done < <(paste -d '|' file1 file2)
```

By choosing a delimiter which doesn't appear in your data, this will work even if the data includes spaces (for example).

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution using classic shell - rather than Bash-specific - constructs uses:

```
paste file1 file2 |
while read i j
do echo $i and $j
done
```

This assumes that there are no spaces in the data from file1 (the spaces in file2 are handled anyway because `j` gets the second and subsequent words on each line of input).  If you need to worry about that, then you can tinker with IFS, etc:

```
paste -d'|' file1 file2 |
while IFS='|' read i j
do echo $i and $j
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

state=0
for i in $(paste file1 file2) ; do
    if [[ $state -eq 0 ]] ; then
        state=1
        save=$i
    else
        state=0
        echo $save and $i
    fi
done
```

With the two input files:

```
$ cat file1
1
2
3
4
5
```

and:

```
$ cat file2
a
b
c
d
e
```

you get the following output:

```
1 and a
2 and b
3 and c
4 and d
5 and e
```

This script uses paste to basically create a new sequence of arguments alternating between the two files, then a very simple state machine to pick up and process the pairs.

Keep in mind it won't work if your lines contain white space but I'm assuming that's not an issue since your original script didn't either.